# layout_toRightOf works and layout_toLeftOf doesn't, how to solve?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have simple relative layout - an ImageView (iv1) and a TextView (tv1) to the left of iv1. Unfortunately, I see no tv1. What is more, even hierarchyViewer can't help me find it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right"
android:background="@android:color/white"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It looks like that:

[image]

However, if I change android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv1" to android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv1", my text view becomes positioned to right of image view. It seems like toRightOf works and toLeftOf doesn't.
Here how it looks:

[image]

What is the matter? How to make layout_toLeftOf work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set imageview property `align_parent_right= true;`

Answer (score 5):

Change:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/+iv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

to:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/iv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

You are using @+id/iv1 in your toLeftOf in the TextView instead of @id/iv1.
Also you should give the imageview a specific place in the view. Try to align it: layout_parentTop = true

Comment: As far as I understand @+id means to create a new id and @id means using already existing object. However, if I replace my layout as you suggested, I get "Couldn't resolve resource @id/iv1". What is it due to?

Comment: If you get it while trying to view your layout (not the code but the actual view) it's a bug. Sometimes Eclipse doesn't get the changes made in your layout. I sove this sometimes by switching between the xml code and the view of my layout twice...

Answer (score 0):

In my case (not in this layout) a problem was in `android:layout_width` of RelativeLayout. When it was `wrap_content` or `match_parent`, a layout became scattered. When I set it as, for instance, 300dp, everything was good.